# Problema con el posicionamiento de texto al lado de una imagen

Tags: html, html5

estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto y tengo un problema con algo que me molesta la verdad, no es tan importante pero a mi parecer queda bastante feo, lo que pasa es que quiero posicionar texto al lado de una imagen pero parte de este queda debajo, las fotos a continuación son de como esta y como debería quedar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo html:

```
 <img src="imagenes/iconoPDF.png" width="35px" height="35px">
    <a style="text-decoration: none;"
      href="https://www.municipalidadgorbea.cl/transparencia/images/ArchivosHOME/DOM/Solicitudes%20de%20obras/1.%20Permisos%20de%20obra%20menor/1-1.2.-Solicitud-Obra-Menor-Modificacion-edificaciones-existentes-que-no-alteren-su-estructura.pdf">Modificación
      edificaciones existentes que no alteren su estructura</a>
```

Comment: Puedes usar `display: flex` en el elemento que contiene a la imagen y al link

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, no se como no se me ocurrió, mil gracias.